# elFinder: Multiple FTP(roots)

Tags: javascript, php, configuration, ftp, file-transfer

I can successfully open **a single FTP** connection from *elFinder*(in combination with or without a different driver like LocalFileSystem, MySQL etc..)

But, I'm unable to **open 2 or more FTP** connections in the same *elFinder* window.

I've tried the following configuration, but no luck, so far:

```
'roots' => array(
    array(
        'driver'        => 'FTP',
        'host'          => 'host1',
        'user'          => 'usr1',
        'pass'          => 'pwd1',
        'port'          => 21,
        'mode'          => 'passive',
        'path'          => '/',
        'timeout'       => 20,
        'alias'         => 'My FTP 1',
        'owner'         => true,
        'tmbPath'       => '/tmp',
        'tmpPath'       => '/tmp',
        'dirMode'       => 0755,
        'fileMode'      => 0644
    ),array(
        'driver'        => 'FTP',
        'host'          => 'host2',
        'user'          => 'usr2',
        'pass'          => 'pwd2',
        'port'          => 21,
        'mode'          => 'passive',
        'path'          => '/',
        'timeout'       => 20,
        'alias'         => 'My FTP 2',
        'owner'         => true,
        'tmbPath'       => '/tmp',
        'tmpPath'       => '/tmp',
        'dirMode'       => 0755,
        'fileMode'      => 0644
    )
)
```

P.S. I can successfully open a `FTP/LocalFileSystem` pair of roots, but how can I open a `FTP/FTP` pair? Am I missing something?